# Mostrar resultado html y php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hola tengo un problema con el siguiente código pues me muestra un resultado de cero no se por que no me lee la función del php, serian tan amables de indicarme que estoy haciendo mal, muchas gracias.

```js
<script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 

 $( document ).ready(function() 
 {
       
  $("#boton_calcular").click(function()
  {
   $.post("procesa_T3.php",
   {
    // Pedir que capture los valores
    N1: $("#N1C").val(),
    N2: $("#N2C").val(),
    E1: $("#E1C").val(),
    E2: $("#E2C").val(),

   },
   function(data, status){
    console.log("Datos recibidos: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    if(status=='success')
    {
     $("#caja_resultado").html( data );
    }
   });
   
  });
 
    });
 
 
 
 
 
 </script>
```

```css
<?php 

 //Capturo parametros procedentes de T3.html
 $N1C = $_POST['N1C'];
 $N2C = $_POST['N2C'];
 $E1C = $_POST['E1C'];
 $E2C = $_POST['E2C'];


 
 //Calculo la distancia entre los puntos
 function distance($x1, $x2, $e1, $e2)
{
  $resultado = ( (abs($x1)) + (abs($x2)) + (abs($e1)) + (abs($e2)));
     return $resultado;
}

 
 //Calculo las coordenadas de el punto
  $valor_devuelto = distance($N1C,$N2C,$E1C,$E2C);
 
 echo 'Coordenadas calculadas : <b>'. $valor_devuelto . '</b>';


?>
```

```html
<body>


N1 <input type="text" id="N1C" value="45"> </input>
E1 <input type="text" id="E1C" value="4"> </input>


<br>
N2<input type="text" id="N2C" value="7"></input>
E2<input type="text" id="E2C" value="88"> </input>

<br><br>

<button id="boton_calcular"> Calcular Distancia Euclidiana</button> <br> <br>

<br><br>

<div id="caja_resultado"> </div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

```
 <script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {

        $("#boton_calcular").click(function()
        {
            $.post("procesa_T3.php",
            {
                // Pedir que capture los valores
                N1: $("#N1C").val(),
                N2: $("#N2C").val(),
                E1: $("#E1C").val(),
                E2: $("#E2C").val(),

            },
            function(data, status){
                console.log("Datos recibidos: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                if(status=='success')
                {
                    $("#caja_resultado").html( data );
                }
            });

        });

    });





    </script>
```

```html
<body>


N1 <input type="text" id="N1C" value="45"> </input>
E1 <input type="text" id="E1C" value="4"> </input>


<br>
N2<input type="text" id="N2C" value="7"></input>
E2<input type="text" id="E2C" value="88"> </input>

<br><br>

<button id="boton_calcular"> Calcular Distancia Euclidiana</button> <br> <br>

<br><br>

<div id="caja_resultado"> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, Veo que existe una inconsistencia en el archivo php.

Asi lo tienes:

```
...
$N1C = $_POST['N1C'];
$N2C = $_POST['N2C'];
$E1C = $_POST['E1C'];
$E2C = $_POST['E2C'];
...
```

Y deberia quedar asi:

```
...
$N1C = $_POST['N1'];
$N2C = $_POST['N2'];
$E1C = $_POST['E1'];
$E2C = $_POST['E2'];
...
```

Si te das cuenta, en el jquery estas enviando los datos con ese nombre de variable (N1,N2,E1,E2)

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te puedes basar muy bien en esto para ver que pasa con tu jQuery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.post demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte